# Is there a jquery tool like this available?

Tags: jquery, image

I need to "build" images for a client's website. There will be one core image and then several other interchangeable images that will stack on top of it.

So, in the admin portion of the site, the user will be able to view the core image and click on it to set points (which we are calling registration points) that will set where the other images will show up when the final image is built.

Just wondering if anyone has ever done anything similar to this or if there is some kind of jquery tool out there that could really help me accomplish this.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

couldnt find one for you, so you'll have to build it yourself.

I've made a little demo here, where admin can click on a map and insert markers using a html5 canvas.

What you need to do else is store the data and make it available to the live page as a json array.

http://jsfiddle.net/QLT4v/

Theres a few loose ends, but note how clicks on top image is represented by flags on the bottom map. The textbox in between holds the data you need to store and present.

Hope it points you towards a solution

EDIT:

Updated version shows solution using absolutely positioned divs. Note the position:relative on the parent div. Probably what caused problems in your admin part.

con: not one image..
pro: not one image -> easy to attach functionality like hover/onclick to items

http://jsfiddle.net/QLT4v/1/

Comment: Thanks Steen. I was using the same kind of logic to save the points so far. But when I showed them again in the admin, so that a user could see where the points were and make any changes, they wouldn't show exactly where they were before. I basically had a div with the core image as the background, and then would place divs on top of that with the point images inside of them. It seemed like the size of the first divs would push the other divs lower or something like that. So maybe the answer is to use the canvas tag.

Comment: I have yet to use the canvas tag myself. Won't I run into problems with older browsers using it?

Comment: for html support check http://findmebyip.com/litmus or other. BUT no reason to do so if you would be happy with positioned images on top of the "master" image. See the updated jsfiddle. Note the button to click to add the needed images.